# jQuery Array.find() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Jquery 3.3.1.
I have the following code:

```
var r =   $("#MultiSelectDialog_List").attr("data-object");
```

where r is an array of objects.
I am trying to find and object by ID so I wrote:

```
r.find(x => x.ID == "5").ID;
```

but when debugging in the browser,an error is thrown (find is not a function)
also the intellisense does not show the find() but shows all other JQuery functions

Comment: attr function returns the value of attribute(string type), There's no find function on string type

Comment: check the typeof r, it will be string

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `attr()` returns a string. If you placed an array of objects in that property, use `data('object')` to retrieve it instead.

Comment: Thank you, what I did is that in data-object i saved a JsonArray, so how can I get it back?

Comment: In that case you need to parse the JSON back to an object; `r = JSON.parse(r);`

Comment: I tried it, but returns ( Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1)..
r is : r = "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"

Comment: provide the format of data in data-object, so as to support you in parsing it

Comment: Thank you all for your help, your comments directed me to the solution. I store the Jsonarray in a global JS variable instead the data-object attribute..all fine now.. many thanks